# Reference Request: Generalization of spectral theory to symmetric KL divergence type metrics?

Tags: sp.spectral-theory

Spectral theory(Courant Fischer Theorem) provides a definition of the spectrum in term of the minima/maxima of the rayleigh coefficient of a matrix. So I can say that kth eigenvector and associated eigenvalue $\lambda_k$ maximizes amongst all subspaces of dimension k the minima of the rayleigh coefficient . The **rayleigh coefficient in turn is related to the cosine distance** between input vector $x$ and its image $Ax$.

**How can I find the spectrum of a matrix in terms of other types of distances** ? For example one could define $\lambda'_k$ to be the eigen value that minimizes the symmetric KL divergence between x and Ax.

I don't really know complex analysis yet so it might just be that this is a standard example in some textbook.